# Euro character € Code page issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, db2

We have recently upgraded Java(7 to 8), Spring(3 to 4), Hibernate(3 to 4) in our application. Afterwards we are facing issues with special characters like (öüä).These values are getting replaced with some junk characters in the database.

When i checked the jsp page i found the code page is "iso-8859-1", so i changed to "UTF-8".Now the special characters are working fine but again we are facing issues with euro(€) symbol.

When i searched in google i found that it could be related with data base code page issue. I checked the data base(DB2) code page and it is is "iso-8859-1. But it is not possible to change the code page in database.

In production environment still all the special characters including euro symbol is working fine with "iso-8859-1" code page. I am still not able to understand how is it working.

Upgrading Java(7 to 8), Spring(3 to 4), Hibernate(3 to 4) really creating the code page issue. How can i resolve euro charcter issue now.

Could any one provide some suggestions.

Update: Database(DB2) is running on Linux server. Before Upgrading Java(7 to 8), Spring(3 to 4), Hibernate(3 to 4) all the special characters were working fine with "iso-8859-1" code page in all the environments(UAT and DEV). In production DB if I use € symbol in jsp page it is getting replaced with question mark(?) symbol. But in UAT DB is getting replaced by the arrow kind of symbol ().

I executed the query given by mao, i am getting the same results in Prod and UAT environments.

[image: Code page details]

Comment: Which operating-system runs the Db2-server (Z/OS, iSeries, Linux, Unix, Windows) ?

Comment: It sounds like your prod environment is fully `ISO-8859-1` and in another environment you have something different (such as the platform default encoding). First you need to find the place where the corruption is happening; reading from the database, displaying the text in JSP or somewhere in between.

Comment: Database(DB2) is running on Linux server. Before Upgrading Java(7 to 8), Spring(3 to 4), Hibernate(3 to 4) all the special characters were working fine with "iso-8859-1" code page in all the environments(UAT and DEV). In production DB if I use € symbol in jsp page it is getting replaced with question mark(?) symbol. But in UAT DB is getting replaced by the arrow kind of symbol ().

Comment: ISO-8859-1 does not have the Euro symbol, that was added in ISO-8859-15 (which is similar to ISO-8859-1, but replaced the ¤ with € (Euro symbol), and some other changes). In other words when you try to store the Euro symbol into something that accepts ISO-8859-1, then Java will convert the € to a ? because that is the default replacement character for unmappable characters.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the results of these TWO queries , showing results on a "working" environment and also on a "failing" environment.  (1) select char(release_num,10) as release_num, char(service_level,20) as service_level, char(bld_level,20) as bld_level, fixpack_num, char(ptf,30) as ptf from sysibmadm.env_inst_info ;    and (2) SELECT char(NAME,50) as name, char(VALUE,100) as val FROM SYSIBMADM.DBCFG where name in ('territory','codepage','codeset') order by 1;

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Db2-LUW V10.5, with codepage 819, Db2 is working correctly for your current configuration.

The reason (as noted by Mark Rotteveel in a comment )is that ISO-8859-1 does not include the euro symbol. When performing Insert/Update, Db2 will do codepage conversion if the application codepage differs from the database-codepage, and that conversion replaces unknown characters (those that are not in the database codepage) by a question-mark.

See also this [page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.nls.doc/doc/t0004584.html) in the Db2 knowledge center, in particular the section 'What to do next' for codepage 819.

You may want to plan migrating to ISO-8859-15 codepage 923 (which means re-creating the database) and migrating the data, which is simple enough but involves an outage.  Another option is to recreate the database with a UTF-8 encoding (this involves more testing). Neither approach will fix data that is already incorrect in the tables, but any newly inserted or updated data will be OK *provided you ensure that the application-codepage matches the database codepage*.

Comment: Thanks @mao for your response. I can understand i have to change the DB2 code page but that is not simple. Still i am not able to understand how all the special characters including € symbol working fine with ISO-8859-1 code page in production environment. Any idea how is that working..